# In org-mode, export all internally linked org files when exporting org file to HTML

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode

Let's say I have an org document that looks something like the following.

```
# blog_main.org

This is my blog. 
Here is [[file:page-a][page A]]. 
Here is [[file:page-b][page B]]. 
Enjoy my blog.
```

When I export this to HTML (using `C-c C-e h h`, say), org exports `blog_main.org` to `blog_main.html` and inside `blog_main.html`, the links to page A and page B are `page-a.html` and `page-b.html`. However, org does not actually export `page-a.org` to `page-a.html`.

How do I configure org mode so that when I export an org file, all files that are internally linked are also exported (with the same settings, say)?

Comment: See [Publishing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html#Publishing) in the Org mode manual. You will need to set up an `org-publish-project-alist` and there are a couple of examples in the link above: the [simple example](https://orgmode.org/manual/Simple-example.html#Simple-example) is probably enough for  your purposes and a good place to start.

Comment: I have looked at this and may try it as a last resort. This approach does not address the question completely, as publishing relies on a "project" structure. It seems like it would be unsuitable for exporting a sub-collection of org files in my main org directory (without publishing all of them) and/or I would have to know the org files I'd like to export, rather than choosing the ones that appear as internal links — an inconvenience. While I've read the manual, I am no org expert; am I wrong about any of this?

Comment: No, you are right about all this, but Org mode does not know what links to what: so either you have to provide to it the project structure to let it know or you have to build whatever mechanism would be required to construct the graph of interrelated files to be exported. Note that you can have multiple projects and one can be a subproject of another: that should take care of the sub-collection case.